# How can I add a template Word file to my visual studio installer file

Tags: c#

i developed a solution to create a word file on visual studio with c#. To do so, i have 2 temnplate word files that i copy a certain times and add them to a whole new document. 
Now i wonder if i want to build a installer file with visual studio installer how can i add this template files to the package and more important what filepath can i add to the App.config. Because the filepath must be variable, since all the computer have diffrent names. So depending on the name there and on the computer the program will be installed on there will be always a different pathname.

greetings cro

Comment: please show us what you already tried

Comment: What do you mean? I can create an installer for my solution. Nothing what i can show to you. What i cant is what i described above.